# access to ... denied problem

Tags: permissions, apache2, vps

so here is my weblog error log file
how to solve these erorrs?

```
[Sat Dec 15 17:05:07.723291 2018] [core:error] [pid 10465:tid 139960006985472] (13)Permission denied: [client 81.198.48.253:58347] AH00035: access to /index.html denied (filesystem path '/home/chroot/websites/specialselektrods.lv/index.html') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

[Sat Dec 15 17:05:07.723446 2018] [core:error] [pid 10465:tid 139960006985472] (13)Permission denied: [client 81.198.48.253:58347] AH00035: access to /index.cgi denied (filesystem path '/home/chroot/websites/specialselektrods.lv/index.cgi') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

[Sat Dec 15 17:05:07.723472 2018] [core:error] [pid 10465:tid 139960006985472] (13)Permission denied: [client 81.198.48.253:58347] AH00035: access to /index.pl denied (filesystem path '/home/chroot/websites/specialselektrods.lv/index.pl') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

[Sat Dec 15 17:05:07.723497 2018] [core:error] [pid 10465:tid 139960006985472] (13)Permission denied: [client 81.198.48.253:58347] AH00035: access to /index.php denied (filesystem path '/home/chroot/websites/specialselektrods.lv/index.php') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

[Sat Dec 15 17:05:07.723521 2018] [core:error] [pid 10465:tid 139960006985472] (13)Permission denied: [client 81.198.48.253:58347] AH00035: access to /index.xhtml denied (filesystem path '/home/chroot/websites/specialselektrods.lv/index.xhtml') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

[Sat Dec 15 17:05:07.723545 2018] [core:error] [pid 10465:tid 139960006985472] (13)Permission denied: [client 81.198.48.253:58347] AH00035: access to /index.htm denied (filesystem path '/home/chroot/websites/specialselektrods.lv/index.htm') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

81.198.48.253 - - [15/Dec/2018:17:05:07 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 516 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
[Sat Dec 15 17:05:08.000730 2018] [core:error] [pid 10465:tid 139960015378176] (13)Permission denied: [client 81.198.48.253:58347] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/chroot/websites/specialselektrods.lv/favicon.ico') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://www.specialselektrods.lv/

81.198.48.253 - - [15/Dec/2018:17:05:08 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 526 "http://www.specialselektrods.lv/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> [Sat Dec 15 17:05:08.000730 2018] [core:error] [pid 10465:tid 139960015378176] (13)Permission denied: [client 81.198.48.253:58347] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/chroot/websites/specialselektrods.lv/favicon.ico') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://www.specialselektrods.lv/
> ```

To be able to change to a directory, it has to have +x, or execute permission. This goes for the whole path.

Add +x to `/home`, `/home/chroot`, `/home/chroot/websites` and so forth, using `chmod +x /path`.